# SELECT + SUM + LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sum

I was hoping to receive some advice. I need to work out how many projects do not have partner allocations of 100%.

One project can have many partners.

The project and partner tables are connected by the `ProjectID`.

I need to select project id, project name FROM project where partner_% != 100%.

So I was thinking along the lines of

```
SELECT project id, project name, SUM (partner_%) as [Project Partner Total]
FROM Project Table
  LEFT JOIN [partner table]
  ON project.projectID = partner.projectID
```

Would my the above work okay for this? (It is SQL Server 2014).

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need a `group by` and a `having` clause:

```
SELECT project id, project name, SUM(partner_%) as [Project Partner Total]
FROM Project Table LEFT JOIN
     [partner table]
     ON project.projectID = partner.projectID
GROUP BY project id, project name
HAVING SUM(partner_%) <> 100;
```

Comment: Perfect, absolutely spot on. Thank you for your help!