# SQL + JOIN on SUM [Part 2]

Tags: sql-server

Good afternoon,

I would like some further advice. Relating to my previous question:
[SELECT + SUM + LEFT JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156420/select-sum-left-join/34156463#34156463)

I need to now do the reverse.

I need to SELECT * Data from the Partner table where the SUM of the partner_% (From the Partner Table) for a project in the (Project Table) is not 100%.

I'm not sure how to code this one; I will need a join to the partner table.

```
 SELECT project id, project name, SUM(partner_%) as [Project Partner Total]
    FROM Project Table LEFT JOIN
         [partner table]
         ON project.projectID = partner.projectID
    GROUP BY project id, project name
    HAVING SUM(partner_%) <> 100;
```

Edit:

So I need to get the partner information from the partner table where the SUM of the partner_% does not equal 100 for projects.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?   Are you getting an error?

Comment: I don' see any issue with your query except that your having condition could just be `HAVING SUM(partner_%) < 100;`

Comment: The above code works fine; however by 'Reverse' I mean I need to get the partner information from the Partner table where the SUM of the partner_% does not equal to 100% for projects.

Comment: Add the required fields of project table in the `SELECT` AND `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 2):

You should rather use an inner query to get the projects first. Then you can join partners.

If you try to do it in one join, you will have problems with grouping. You need to group projects only, not partners.

```
SELECT partner.*, PR.*
FROM partner
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT project id, project name, SUM(partner_%) as [Project Partner Total]
    FROM Project
    LEFT JOIN partner ON project.projectID = partner.projectID
    GROUP BY project id, project name
    HAVING SUM(partner_%) <> 100) PR
ON PR.projectID = partner.projectID
```

Comment: The partner_% is located in the Partner table; Which give s me the usual 'could not be bound' error message?

I found that, if I add the Partner table into the FROM Section of the INNER JOIN the sum returns a value of 3417739.77 for all rows :(

Comment: Ok, didn't know that (please provide the structure of your tables in questions). Anyway, I added one more join to the query, following your example from the question. The way stays the same: first get the right projects, then get partners.